# Data Received from Laravel API Server Not Shown on Flutter Screen

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, flutter

I am trying to receive data from Laravel php server and show it on Flutter Login screen which directs to Dashboard after successful login , but there is no data shown and only the loading icon keeps  loading on screen.

Here is the code of Login:

```
class DashboardState extends State<Dashboard>{

  DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dashboard',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dashboard'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: ()=>
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context)=> new AddData(),
              ))
          ,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: dataBaseHelper.getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? new ItemList(list: snapshot.data)
                  : new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            },
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

And here is getData() function which receive the data from server and located in databasehelper:

```
Future<List> getData() async{
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final key = 'token';
final value =  prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

var url = '$serverUrl/cars/';
final response = await http.get(url,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json',
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer $value'
    },

);
return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Note I receive the following message on console when the user logged in and go to dashboard:

```
I/flutter ( 9962): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `FutureBuilder<List>` is expecting `List` and `getData` is returning `InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`. Return the object model to increase code readability and expect the same object class for e.g. `FutureBuilder<CustomModel>`. Check [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-apis-in-flutter-8745968103e9).

Comment: Why getData() return internalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> and I already set it to return Futute<List> ??

Comment: You are returning this `json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: Hey, @SanjaySharma can you look into ti please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133740/401-unauthorized-error-in-flutter-but-works-fine-in-postman