# 401 unauthorized error in Flutter but works fine in Postman

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, authorization, integration

I have Laravel endpoints. Login, Register and Home(where getData() will be working).

the register API and Login API is working fine but the problem is with the HomePage API where it will not ask for user details, it's a get method where it will return the details upon checking whether the user is logged-In or not.

```
  var token;

  _getKey() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = prefs.getString('key');
    print("this is Key $token");
  }
saveKey(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('key', key);
  }
  getData() async {
    await _getCSRF();
    await _getKey();
    print(_setAuthHeaders());
    String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";
    try {
      return await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: _setAuthHeaders());
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }

  _setAuthHeaders() => {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      };
```

A token is printing here:
[image: This is token]

result of hitting the endpoint in the browser.
[image: This is the header which I want to access]

Please help.

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72789318/11445944

Comment: Typo at `'Authorization': '$token;',`? There is `:` at the end of the `$token`.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I am not using dio. I am using `http`.

Comment: You can use option 1 in my answer, make sure your rest api/server accept lower case header name.

Comment: I haven't found a way for `http` library

Comment: I don't have access to the backend. So option 1 is out of scope.

Comment: Just check if you are actually passing the correct token. Validate it in postman.

Comment: Yes, It is working fine in Postman.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I can provide a repo link. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

`http` library automatically converts the header name to lower-case, may your server not accepting lower-case header name.
Follow this step:

1. Find `io_client.dart` in *External Libraries->Dart Packages->http-x.xx->src->io_client.dart*
2. Find this code inside `io_client.dart` (line 40)

```
request.headers.forEach((name, value) {
  ioRequest.headers.set(name, value);
});
```

3. Add `preserveHeaderCase: true`

```
request.headers.forEach((name, value) {
  ioRequest.headers.set(name, value,preserveHeaderCase:true);
});
```

4. Clean your project and rebuild

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: Please help me. I am stuck for 2 days

Comment: @Arzak - Please accept my thanks for your response. I actually found it very helpful in resolving the problem.

Comment: Tried, but not working for me, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

please pass token as

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token;',
```

Comment: I have already tried it. but not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 _setAuthHeaders() => {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      };
```

Comment: I have tried but not working. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making flutter web project then please check at Inspect >> Console, that **Refused to set unsafe header "content-length"** is printing or not. If its happening then in your code where you have api setup

```
class ApiServiceProvider extends GetConnect {}
```

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      httpClient.addRequestModifier<void>((request) {
        request.headers.remove('user-agent');
        request.headers.remove('content-length');
        return request;
      });
    }
    super.onInit();
  }
```