# Flutter http package get

Tags: flutter, http, get

I have a get method using 'http: ^0.13.5' package.

On Insominia, status code is 200 (using the same url and header), but in my app, I receive error `{"status":409,"message":"Unauthenticated"}`

Is there something wrong in my sintax?

```
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://sys-dev.searchandstay.com/api/admin/house_rules'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization':
          'Bearer 40fe071962846075452a4f6123ae71697463cad20f51e237e2035b41af0513d8',
    },
  );
```

Comment: you should avoid using http. Also, you might check on backend what request reached there in both cases (on insominia and from the app)

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73135932/11445944